# Avoid namespace collision between my test files and the helper functions being tested

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, namespaces

I have some functions that I am requiring into my test files as well as into the helper file being tested. The problem is, depending on which order they are imported, one set of functions ends up undefined. This is easier to show:

fitnessPlanAssignment.test.js

```
/* global jest, it, expect, beforeAll, afterAll, afterEach, describe */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const moment = require('moment');
const faker = require('faker');
const db = require('../models');

const {
  checkFuturePlans,
  determinePlansToAssign,
  assignFitnessPlans,
} = require('../helpers/fitnessPlanAssignment');

const { deleteFuturePlans } = require('../helpers/fitnessplans');

const { assignOneTrack, switchTrack } = require('../helpers/tracks');
```

/helpers/tracks.js

```
const db = require('../models');
const { deleteFuturePlans } = require('./fitnessPlans');
const {
  checkFuturePlans,
  determinePlansToAssign,
  assignFitnessPlans,
} = require('./fitnessPlanAssignment');
console.log(determinePlansToAssign); // undefined
console.log(assignFitnessPlans); // undefined
```

helpers/fitnessPlanAssignment.js

```
const moment = require('moment');
const db = require('../models');

const { createUserFitnessPlan } = require('../helpers/fitnessplans');
const { assignOneTrack } = require('../helpers/tracks');
```

[image]

When I switch this statement:
`const { assignOneTrack, switchTrack } = require('../helpers/tracks');`
to be required first, they are no longer undefined, but now `assignOneTrack()` is undefined. How do I avoid this issue?

Comment: You didn't show mentioned modules. There is most likely a circular dependency between them. It needs to be fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by circular dependency. I've updated the question above to include the require statements from /helpers/fitnessPlanAssignment.js

Comment: CD is a specific tech term. It means that modules depend on each other. In your case fitnessPlanAssignment and tracks import from each other which has no chances to work properly.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that wasn't possible. I'll move some functions around. Thanks!